# R - subsetting original data frame: N random observations, 50% of N has ethnicity E and 50% of N has a education E

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

Hi Stackoverflow users,

I am new at R, and have been learning for a couple of weeks only.
I have a data frame with 15 string variables on people's characteristics (e.g. ethnicity, education, country of origin); one row is one person.

How can I tell R to create a subset of the original data frame such that this new data frame includes N random people (who have been drawn with replacement), 50% of N has Ethnicity ET, and 50% of N has Education ED?
I know the basic **A)** and **B)**

**A)** I know how to draw N observations at random with replacement, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/sample-random-rows-in-dataframe#8273355) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806702/how-do-i-select-a-sample-of-rows-at-random-with-repetition-from-a-matrix-in-r).
For example:

```
df[sample(nrow(df), size=N, replace=TRUE), ]
```

**B)** [In this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989355/extracting-a-random-sample-of-rows-in-a-data-frame-with-a-nested-conditional#19989784), there are examples on how to condition the random draw (without replacement).

```
df[ sample( which( df$Ethnicity== "ET" | df$Education= "ED" ) , N ) , ]
```

However, I would like to know how to make more complex conditional draws, that is, 50% of N has to have Ethnicity ET, and 50% of N has to have Education ED. Thus, in this new sample of size N, the two conditions only partially intersect: for some people Ethnicity==ET & Education==ED, for some people Ethnicity!=ET & Education==ED, for some people Ethnicity==ET & Education!=ED, for some people Ethnicity!=ET & Education!=ED.

Comment: @Andreas Now I have expanded the post to show what I know, what I have found on stackoverflow and give some examples. However, what I am asking in this post is very general and quite complex (given my limited knowledge), I cannot see how this additional information could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to `sample` 1/4 for each combination, hoping that this combination exists:

```
n  <- 1e2 / 4
y <- x[c(sample(which(x$et & x$ed), n, TRUE)
         , sample(which(!x$et & x$ed), n, TRUE)
         , sample(which(x$et & !x$ed), n, TRUE)
         , sample(which(!x$et & !x$ed), n, TRUE)),]
table(y)
#       ed
#et      FALSE TRUE
#  FALSE    25   25
#  TRUE     25   25
```

In case there is a combination which does not exist you can get the proportion of each combination with `table` like:

```
n  <- 1e2
x  <- x[!x$et | x$ed,]
tt  <- table(x)
tt  <- tt * t(tt)
tt <- tt / rowSums(tt) 
tt <- tt / rep(colSums(tt), each=2)
tt <- round(proportions(tt)*n) #Since R 4.0.0: prop.table becomes proportions
#tt <- round(prop.table(tt)*n) #Here the target number might not be reached
y <- x[c(sample(which(!x$et & !x$ed), tt[1], TRUE)
         , sample(which(x$et & !x$ed), tt[2], TRUE)
         , sample(which(!x$et & x$ed), tt[3], TRUE)
         , sample(which(x$et & x$ed), tt[4], TRUE)),]
table(y)
#       ed
#et      FALSE TRUE
#  FALSE    50    0
#  TRUE      0   50
```

Data:

```
set.seed(7)
n  <- 1e4
x  <- data.frame(et=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), n, TRUE, c(.25,.75)), ed=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), n, TRUE, c(.75,.25)))
```

Comment: Is it ok if I turn the subsample into a data frame simply writing:
```y= data.frame(y)``` after ```table(y)```

Comment: what are you doing here: ```x  <- data.frame(et=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), n, TRUE, c(.25,.75)), ed=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), n, TRUE, c(.75,.25)))```?

Comment: @Fuca26 I create an reproducible example dataset.